# Joomla 4.0.3 - LDAP Login / Microsoft AD

Tags: login, joomla-4.x

Which settings and plugins are exactly needed to configure Joomla 4.0.3 with LDAP support?

The AD server is a Windows Server 2016 Standard.

I have  activated the Joomla Plugin **Authentication - LDAP** with the following settings but without success.

| Setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Host | 10.177.xx.xx |
| Port | 389 |
| LDAP V3 | YES |
| Negotiate TLS | NO |
| Ignore Certificate | NO |
| Follow Referrals | NO |
| Authorisation Method | Bind and Search |
| Base DN | DC=xxx-xx,DC=DE |
| Search String | sAMAccountName=[search] |
| User's DN | n/a |
| Connect Username | service.ldap **or** |
|  | service.ldap@xxx-xx.de **or** |
|  | xx-xx\service.ldap **or** |
|  | CN=Service, LDAP,OU=Serviceaccounts,OU=EDV,DC=xxx-xx,DC=DE |
| Connect Password | *********** |
| Map: Full Name | displayName |
| Map: Email | mail |
| Map: User ID | sAMAccountName |